# Show cached pages with boost for logged in users

Tags: 6, caching

I have a website that is only available to logged in users, I want to increase performance with boost by caching pages for authenticated users would i just edit the code above?

http://drupal.org/node/509694

here it says this code is what prevents boost from caching for logged in users

```
<?php
  // For authenticated users, set a special cookie to prevent them
  // inadvertently getting served pages from the static page cache.
  if (!empty($user->uid)) {
    boost_set_cookie($user);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it will break your site for logged in users. Try [Authcache module](https://drupal.org/project/authcache) instead.

Comment: do i need to have memcache or APC installed on my server for this to work?

Comment: No - "By default, Authcache will use the cache_page table to store cached pages."

Comment: But memcached reduces number of queries drastically, And thus it's a huge performance enhancement.